# Ignoring ascii carriage return characters in R

Tags: r, vim, ascii, carriage-return, 4d-database

I've a dataset in tab delimited text file. The data have been exported from an old-school relational database software 4D. Most of the lines seems to be well formated but some lines include an ASCII carriage return character (`^M` in Emacs or Ascii code 13). I would like to read the data in R using a function such as `read.table()` and to find a way to ignore those ascii carriage return symbols. Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Another way to ask the same question would be : how to delete DOS returns ^M in R ?

Comment: You can remove `^M` from dataset before import. There are many ways - you can try perl, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650743/in-perl-how-to-do-you-remove-m-from-a-file)

Comment: That's what I've finally done. I've used Vim to delete all the `^M` from the original text file : `:%s/\r//g` (http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html). It would be great to find a solution from within R.

Comment: I can't replicate this - `read.table` reads mixed endline files just fine for me

Comment: @eddi : Interesting. What's your OS ?

Comment: `> paste(R.Version(), collapse = ",")   [1] "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu,x86_64,linux-gnu,x86_64, linux-gnu,,2,15.0,2012,03,30,58871,R,R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30),"`

Comment: Ok, the problem maybe specific to Mac OS

Comment: Use `readLines()`,replace them using `gsub()` and then do `read.table()`?

Answer (score 0):

In Vim you can create the ^M character by typing control-v control-m

So you could replace every occurence of ^M with:

```
:%s/<c-v><c-m>//g
```